# Run a shell script on Windows - Drupal install using DAMP

Tags: windows, apache, drupal, windows-vista

i've installed DAMP on Windows Vista, and have created a profile in my drupal folder with a shell script that needs to run.

profiles/donor_rally/rebuild.sh

However, I don't know how to execute this shell script.

I am not familiar with shell script command language, would you be willing to provide me with a step-by-step instructions on how to execute this shell script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to run a Bourne shell script, which would usually only run on a unix machine.  Guessing from the name, this is supposed to rebuild something, likely the database, but that's just a guess.

The short answer is you can't run it, at least not easily.  If you were to post the (edited) contents of the script you might get some answers about how you could port it to a Windows cscript or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

For others who are uninitiated to shell scripting in Windows:

I did not find a straightforward solution for running shell scripts on AMP hosted on Windows.

Instead I got an account at webenabled.com

Then used PuTTy to tunnel in.

I found this guide to using UNIX: http://freeengineer.org/learnUNIXin10minutes.html

And lynda.com